# Penalty methods in Unconstrained problems

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, constraint-programming

Let me define $p : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ as a penalty function for the feasible set $\mathcal F$ of an equality and inequality constrained problem $(P)$

$$(P) : \text{min}\space f(x) \space \text{subject to}\space  h(x) = 0 , g(x)\leq 0$$
Where $h(x):= (h_1(x), ..., h_m(x)), g(x):=(g_1(x),...,g_r(x))$

**IF**  it holds that $p(x) = 0 \space \forall \space x \in \mathcal F$ and $p(x) > 0 \space \forall \space x \notin \mathcal F$

So for the following  functions:

$q_1(x) : = \sum_{i=1}^m (h_i(x))^k + \sum_{j=1}^r g_j^+(x)$, with $k \in \mathbb{N}$ an odd number

$q_2(x): = \sum_{i=1}^m \text{exp}h_i(x) + \sum_{j=1}^r \exp g_j^+(x)$

$q_3(x): = \sum_{i=1}^m \ln ((h_i(x))^2+1) + \sum_{j=1}^r(g_j^+(x))^3 $

Can I double check that in fact:

$q_1(x) \text{is not a penalty function}$, (take $h<0$ and then $q<0$)

$q_2(x) $ is not either (at $h=0, q_2 >0$)

$q_3(x) $ is a penalty function.

We can modify $q_1(x)$ to being a penalty function if we take $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is an even number.

I can't think of a way to modify $q_2$ to change it into a penalty function. Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited my original question, could you confirm if I am correct?

Comment: It is correct now.